# Changing colour in ggplot barplot for each x value

Tags: r, ggplot2

Through trial and error I have discovered my ggplot has to look like this in order for `stat_pvalue_manual` to work. If I switch "`fill=`" and "`x=`" I can adjust the colours for `Treatment_Status`, but since my plot has to look like this - how do I change the colour of each bar on the x axis for both facets? At the minute it the only colours are by `c.d.Sex.` (male, female).

These are the colours I want for each Treatment_Status bar on the x-axis.

```
colours <- c("NCS_Con" = "#f77f00", "NCS_PNS" = "#d62828", "CS_Con" = "#fcbf49", "CS_PNS" = "#EAE2B7")
```

```
p1 <- ggplot(corttestunitedmutated2, aes(x=Treatment_Status, y=mean, fill = c.d.Sex.)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
           position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(.~c.d.Sex., scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                      panel.border = element_blank(),
                      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
                      axis.text.x = NULL
                      ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  labs(title="Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
       x = "Status\nTreatment") +
  scale_fill_manual(values =colours) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    femalestats.test1omit, x = "group2", y.position = 620,
    label = "asterisk",
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    hide.ns = TRUE) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    malestats.test1omit, x = "group2", y.position = 700,
    label = "asterisk",
    position = position_dodge(0.9),
    hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Thanks!

edit: data for ggplot: `dput(corttestunitedmutated2)`

edit2:

```
dput(corttestunitedmutated2)
structure(list(Treatment_Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS"
), class = "factor"), c.d.Sex. = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), N = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L), mean = c(793.185103222222, 415.2964824, 
491.711204444444, 337.354349777778, 828.866709611111, 470.6272386, 
617.146221777778, 521.39674985), sd = c(139.479678927179, 183.047203537505, 
115.471138211954, 78.2702347304746, 176.119561017744, 132.014450160878, 
167.489275167574, 181.880434256998), se = c(46.4932263090596, 
57.8846082502948, 38.4903794039847, 26.0900782434915, 58.7065203392481, 
41.7466346563155, 55.8297583891913, 57.5156434072629)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please use a public dataset (e.g., `mtcars`, `iris`, `diamonds`) or provide sample data with `dput(head(corttestunitedmutated2,n))` (where `n` is a small number that provides enough variability to demonstrate a proper plot). Thanks!

Comment: i don't get it. if sex is a factor of **two** unique values (male and female), why are you using **four** colours? it seems that your colours vector should have two colours only..

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga I’m trying to add colours to the Status_Treatment (NCS_Con, NCS_PNS, CS_Con, CS_PNS) rather than the sex.

Comment: @DS14 share with us a piece of your dataframe. as mentioned by @r2evans, copying and pasting the output of `dput(head(corttestunitedmutated2, 10))` would be enough for us to try to reproduce your problem.. i think i can help you out then

Comment: thanks @rodolfoksveiga - dput added!

Comment: Since we don't have the data, we could not reproduce the plot. But it seems like you need to change `geom_bar(aes(color=Status_Treatment),stat="identity")` and  add `scale_color_discrete()` method to your ggplot. @DS14

Comment: @DS14, you should run the function `dput(corttestunitedmutated2)` and copy and paste the output that was printed on screen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the colour of each bar, regarding the **Treatment_Status** variable, changing `fill = c.d.Sex.` to `fill = Treatment_Status` and setting it inside the `geom_bar()`, as follows:

```
colours <- c("NCS_Con" = "#f77f00", "NCS_PNS" = "#d62828", "CS_Con" = "#fcbf49", "CS_PNS" = "#EAE2B7")

p1 <- ggplot(corttestunitedmutated2, aes(x = Treatment_Status, y = mean)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Treatment_Status),
           colour = "black",
           stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),
                width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(.~c.d.Sex.,
             scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background  = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                     panel.border = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
       x = "Status\nTreatment") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(femalestats.test1omit,
                     x = "group2",
                     y.position = 620,
                     label = "asterisk",
                     position = position_dodge(0.9),
                     hide.ns = TRUE) +
  stat_pvalue_manual(malestats.test1omit,
                     x = "group2",
                     y.position = 700,
                     label = "asterisk",
                     position = position_dodge(0.9),
                     hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Let us know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you! I get an error message though: `Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomBar,  : 
  object 'Treatment_Status' not found`

Comment: i'm sorry @DS14, i have just fixed a bug. try it out now.

Comment: hi @rodolfoksveiga I am getting a new error message `Error: geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: x or y, xmin and xmax` BUT when I comment out the geom_errorbar, we're getting somewhere.... the outlines of the bars are now the right colours, but the bars themselves are still coloured by sex.


Edit: I also want to thank you for helping me out here. I started using r three weeks ago and am learning by doing, so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: don't worry @DS14. that's a nice thing about r, the community is very helpful! so, i edited my post again and i think now you'll get the output that you want.. please, remember upvoting my answer if i solve your problem. upvote the answer, not the comment..

Comment: it's always important to like (upvote) the answers when they're right, it's a way to pay back their help. you can also set an answer as the best one, the person will earn extra points in stack overflow, which is very nice too!